# Use of VAR when taking corner kicks

Tags: rules, football, video-review

Why doesn't the VAR get used at corner kicks, very often the ball is outside the semi circle, should a team score from the corner kick, should it be allowed

Comment: I highly doubt that players at the level where VAR is available are being allowed to place the ball outside the corner arc.

Answer (score 1):

For a corner kick the ball does not have to be within the arc of the corner. The ball simply has to break the plane of the arc for it to be in a valid position. So it can be outside the arc, and 1mm of the ball overhanging the white line of the arc and it will be valid placement. See [here](http://www.askasoccerreferee.com/ball-placement-at-corner-kick-and-penalty-kick/).

The reason I believe why VAR would not be used for this because it is a very minute offence should be ball not be breaking the plane of the arc. If VAR was used corner kicks, it would then have to be used for the EXACT placement for free kicks and goal kicks also (where the same rule for breaking the plane of the line applies).

So yes, the goal should be allowed to stand.

Comment: If a goal is scored as the result of an offence by the attacking team, it would absolutely incorrect for VAR not to request OFR on the placement. Free kicks don't have any such requirement for an exact placement on a field marking; goal kicks cannot score goals and are outside the VAR protocol anyway.

Comment: @Nij Goal kicks can absolutely score goals. VAR should only be used when there is a "clear and obvious error". Depending on the circumstances of the ball placement at the corner, you're right VAR may get involved. As far as I'm aware, VAR has never been involved with the issue above so until that happens I guess we won't know the true answer.

Comment: If the ball is outside of the corner arc and does not touch it, it's a clear rule violation. If the ball was clearly outside this should be reviewed by the VAR if a goal was scored.

Comment: @dly The ball is allowed to be outside the corner arc, as long as the ball breaks the plane of the arc.

Comment: that's what I mean by touching it

Comment: If any part of the ball is directly above any part of the arc, the ball is inside the arc by definition. Saying it's "outside the arc" while also "breaking the plane of the arc" does not make sense.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, It would be allowed. Why VAR isn't used for that is in my own idea not to add to time wasting. And they are professionals so.

Comment: Allowing a goal to be awarded after it was clearly outside the corner arc would be entirely within the remit of VAR, and it would be absolutely incorrect to not use it, especially "not to add to time wasting".